# Perform same task on multiple objects in the environment using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have these data:

```
u1 <- 'www.link1.com'
u2 <- 'www.link2.com'
u3 <- 'www.link3.com'
u4 <- 'www.link4.com'
```

I want to do some work on them, how can I use for-loop to do this?!

```
for (i in u1 : ur4)
{
  texti <- gettxt(i)
}
```

Comment: save them as a `vector` i.e. `u[1] <- 'www.link1.com'` and so on. Then run the for loop over `1:4`.

Comment: `urls <- c("www.link1.com", "www.link2.com", ...)`, then `alltext <- lapply(urls, gettxt)` will do all that.

Comment: Do they always start with "u"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `sapply` with `get` to obtain the value of the object.

The first argument of `sapply` depends on how many urls do you have.

```
sapply(1:4, function(x) gettext(get(paste0("u", x))))
[1] "www.link1.com" "www.link2.com" "www.link3.com" "www.link4.com"
```

### Updated

If you wish to export the `gettxt` results to individual vectors, you can use the following (note that `lapply` is used here instead of `sapply`):

```
setNames(lapply(1:4, function(x) gettxt(get(paste0("u", x)))), paste0("u", 1:4, "_txt")) %>% 
  list2env(envir = globalenv())
```

Where it'll output four vectors with the names as `u1_txt` to `u4_txt`

```
grep("^u", ls(), value = T)
[1] "u1"     "u1_txt" "u2"     "u2_txt" "u3"     "u3_txt" "u4"    
[8] "u4_txt"
```

### Example

I've used some dummy sites to test the codes.

```
u1 <- "https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=htm2txt"
u2 <- "https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr"
u3 <- "https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyverse"
u4 <- "https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyr"

setNames(lapply(1:4, function(x) gettxt(get(paste0("u", x)))), paste0("u", 1:4, "_txt")) %>% 
  list2env(envir = globalenv())

grep("^u", ls(), value = T)
[1] "u1"     "u1_txt" "u2"     "u2_txt" "u3"     "u3_txt" "u4"    
[8] "u4_txt"

u1_txt
[1] "htm2txt: Convert Html into Text\n\nConvert a html document to simple plain texts by removing all html tags. This package utilizes regular expressions to strip off html tags. It also offers gettxt() and browse() function, which enables you to get or browse texts at a certain web page.\n\nVersion: 2.1.1\n\nDepends: R (≥ 3.0.0)\n\nPublished: 2017-10-19\n\nAuthor: Sangchul Park [aut, cre]\n\nMaintainer: Sangchul Park <mail at sangchul.com>\n\nBugReports: https://github.com/sangchulpark/htm2txt/issues\n\nLicense: GPL-2 | GPL-3 [expanded from: GPL (≥ 2)]\n\nURL: https://github.com/sangchulpark\n\nNeedsCompilation: no\n\nIn views: WebTechnologies\n\nCRAN checks: htm2txt results\n\nDocumentation:\n\nReference manual: htm2txt.pdf\n\nDownloads:\n\nPackage source: htm2txt_2.1.1.tar.gz\n\nWindows binaries: r-devel: htm2txt_2.1.1.zip, r-release: htm2txt_2.1.1.zip, r-oldrel: htm2txt_2.1.1.zip\n\nmacOS binaries: r-release (arm64): htm2txt_2.1.1.tgz, r-release (x86_64): htm2txt_2.1.1.tgz, r-oldrel: htm2txt_2.1.1.tgz\n\nOld sources: htm2txt archive\n\nReverse dependencies:\n\nReverse imports: getDEE2\n\nLinking:\n\nPlease use the canonical form https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=htm2txt to link to this page."
```

Comment: Similarly using mget: `sapply(mget(grep("^u", ls(), value = TRUE)), gettext)`

Comment: Good alternative! But `microbenchmark` shows that my code might be more efficient B-)

Comment: @benson23 Very useful - And now, how do I use function `gettxt` to get texts from these links?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this function. Does `sapply(1:4, function(x) gettxt(get(paste0("u", x))))` work?

Comment: @benson23 Yes, it worked, but I want to access the text on each website. do it via `text <- gettxt(URL)`. And now I have many links (URLs) I want to get their text.

Comment: See if my updated answer is what you want.

Comment: @benson23 Your code gives URLs in a list (It is excellent). in the second step, I want to store the texts which are on these websites.

Comment: Again, I've added some dummy websites to test, it seems to work.

Comment: @benson23 Yes, many thanks, it worked. however, some websites aren't stored because of this error: `Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established.'`
- Can you help me; How can I fix it?

Comment: I cannot help you with this since I've never used this function before

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @slowowl and @r2evans, you don't need a loop as R is vectorized. Consider storing the URLs in a vector.

You can do that as follows:

```
URLs <- c('www.link1.com', 'www.link2.com', 'www.link3.com', 'www.link4.com')
```

And then you can use `lapply` over this vector as follows:

```
text <- lapply(URLs, gettext)
```

To make a vector from individual variables you can use the following code:

```
vec <- c()
for (i in 1:4) {
  vec <- c(vec, get(sprintf("u%i", i)))
}
```

```
[1] "www.link1.com" "www.link2.com" "www.link3.com" "www.link4.com"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response.
1) As I have many URLs, are you have a way to make a list automatically? I mean that I have to put manually all of the links in `c()` or does it has a way to do it?

2) when I use `lapply()` I face an error `Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection`

@slowowl , @r2evans , @Visha A.

Comment: What are the links stored as? Are they stored as an individual variable?

Comment: Yes, they are stored in individual variables. 
`u1 <- 'www.link1.com'
u2 <- 'www.link2.com'
u3 <- 'www.link3.com'
u4 <- 'www.link4.com'`

Comment: Remove sapply solution at the end, it was already posted by benson before you.

Comment: I have given the credits to @benson23.

Comment: No need, it already exists, why duplicate.

Comment: If benson has a problem, I'll remove it.

Comment: Nevermind, we're all trying to learn something here :)

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback!
@Vishal A. @benson23
- And now, how do I use function `gettxt` to get texts from these links?